# Prolog - Issue with clause going both ways

Tags: prolog

I have a set of rules;

```
family(Mother,Father,Children).
```

Where children is a list (e.g. `[ag, bg]`).

```
parent(X,Y) :-
    family(X,_,_) -> mother(X,Y); father(X,Y).
```

With the clause above it correctly gives me the children if I put in a parent. However if I put a child in I cannot get the parents.

I have also tried to make a clause for Child;

```
child(X,Y) :-
    mother(A,X),
    father(B,X),
    Y=A,B.
```

Where mother and father work correctly, but I need both variables to go to `Y`.

Any advice?

Comment: Try this parent clause: `parent(X,Y) :- family(X,_,Y), (mother(X,Y); father(X,Y)).`

Comment: @bob_saginowski I attempted that however even though it finds both parents correctly, it return false and it does not print them out as Y=jb1, Y=rb1.

Comment: And child clause could be miplified: `child(X,Y) :- mother(Y,X); father(Y,X).`

Comment: @bob_saginowski Thank you that worked, if you have a moment would you mind explain ; to me?

Comment: @JoeBoggs `;` means logical `or` (`||` in languages like Java, C++, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the child predicate:

```
child(X,Y) :- mother(Y,X); father(Y,X).
```